# Launching an executeable file from R

Tags: r, rstudio

I apologize if this question was answer elsewhere. I have an executable file that I need to run from R. Basically I want to use R to create the input files this executable requires, then run it, and finally use R again to analyze the output files. Because I have to do this many times I'd like to have the R code call the executable file after the input files are ready. Thanks for any help.

Furqan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `system` command

from the help page:

> `system` invokes the OS command specified by command.

An example would be:

```
system(paste('"c:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe"',
             '-url cran.r-project.org'), wait = FALSE)
```

or:

```
system("gzip mydat.csv", wait=FALSE)
```

Maybe the `wait` parameter should be set on `TRUE` in your case, to ensure that the program has finished.